# Accessing data from file A using an element shared with a file B (Foreign Keys)

Tags: c, file, foreign-keys, structure

I have a file car.txt and a file reservation.txt. Both the files have a reservation number (Rxxx).

I want to use the reservation number from reservation.txt to print the details of the car with the corresponding reservation number. Or more accurately, I'm trying to find the details of all the cars that are available at any given date.

car.txt:
(from let to right: reservationID, carID, carYOM, carMake, carModel, carFuel, catagory)

```
R002;V001;2003;Toyota;Camry;Petrol;Budget
R007;V002;2005;Toyota;Prius;Petrol;Economy
R001;V003;1999;Ford;Falcon;Petrol;Midsize
R008;V004;2007;Ford;Territory;Diesel;Fullsize
R011;V005;2010;Ferrari;599;Petrol;Fullsize
R035;V006;1998;Holden;Comadore;Diesel;Midsize
R006;V007;2008;Honda;Civic;Petrol;Budget
R004;V008;2000;Mazda;MX5;Petrol;Economy
```

reservation.txt:
(from let to right: reservationID, customerID, reservationStartDate, reservationStartTime, reservationEndDate, reservationEndTime)

```
R001;C005;12/02/2012;09:15A.M;15/03/2012;05:00P.M
R002;C002;15/04/2012;10:00A.M;22/04/2012;10:30A.M
R003;C003;16/01/2012;02:11P.M;15/04/2012;12:00P.M
R004;C004;05/05/2012;03:00P.M;08/05/2012;10:40A.M
R005;C005;15/04/2012;10:00A.M;23/04/2012;05:00P.M
R006;C006;11/04/2012;05:30P.M;15/04/2012;10:00A.M
R010;C008;15/05/2012;03:15P.M;18/05/2012;11:00A.M
R011;C007;15/04/2012;11:40P.A;23/04/2012;09:00A.M
```

If I enter any date It only gets up to the point where it decides if the entered date is between the reservation start and end date. "all the cars are available".

However, if I enter 13/02/2012, It prints "no matching resID in cars.txt" 7 times.

The code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CAR 100
#define MAX_RES 100

int main(){

    typedef struct{                 //car struct
        char reservationID[20];
        char carID[20];
        char carYOM[20];
        char carMake[20];
        char carModel[50];
        char carFuel[20];
        char catagory[20];
    } car_t;

    typedef struct{                 //res struct
        char reservationID[20];
        char customerID[20];
        char reservationStartDate[20];
        char reservationStartTime[20];
        char reservationEndDate[50];
        char reservationEndTime[20];
    } res_t;

    car_t car[MAX_CAR];             //car array
    res_t reservation[MAX_RES];     //res array
    FILE *carHandle;
    FILE *resHandle;
    char line[100];
    char *item;
    int rescount = 0;
    int carcount =0;
    int k;
    int i;
    int option;
    char choice[20];    

    resHandle = fopen("reservation.txt","r");    

    while (fgets(line, 99, resHandle)){                         //cut up the reservation file line by line and put the bits into the res array.
        item = strtok(line,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].customerID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationStartDate,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationStartTime,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationEndDate,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationEndTime,item);
        rescount++;
    }

    fclose(resHandle);

    carHandle = fopen("car.txt","r");    

    while (fgets(line, 99, carHandle)){                                 //cut up the car file line by line and put the bits into the car array.
        item = strtok(line,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].reservationID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carYOM,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carMake,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carModel,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carFuel,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
        strcpy(car[carcount].catagory,item);
        carcount++;
    }

    fclose(carHandle);

    printf("Enter todays date:");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    for (k=0;k<=rescount; k++){
        if (strcmp(choice,reservation[k].reservationEndDate)<0 && strcmp(choice,reservation[k].reservationStartDate)>0){
            for (i=0;i<=carcount; i++){
                if (strcmp(car[k].reservationID,reservation[i].reservationID)==0){
                    printf("\nreservationID: %s\nreservationStartTime: %s\ncustomerID: %s\ncarid: %s\nyom: %s\nmake: %s\nmodel: %s\nfueltype: %s\ncategory: %s\n\n", car[k].reservationID, reservation[i].reservationStartTime, reservation[i].customerID, car[k].carID, car[k].carYOM, car[k].carMake, car[k].carModel, car[k].carFuel, car[k].catagory);
                    //printf("This works");
                    goto outofloop;
                }else printf("\n\nno matching resID in cars.txt\n");
            }
        }
        else printf("\nall the cars are available\n");
        break;
    }
    outofloop:

    return(0);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT: Updated code.

This is the output, still wrong :(:

Enter todays date:13/02/2012

no matching resID in cars.txt

```
reservationID: R002
reservationStartTime: 10:00A.M
customerID: C002
carid: V001
yom: 2003
make: Toyota
model: Camry
fueltype: Petrol
category: Budget

Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

Enter todays date:13/02/2012

all the cars are available

Press any key to continue...

Comment: You use **only one** counter for both of your arrays, that are `car` and `reservation`.

Comment: Are you sure c is the right choice here? your task sounds like a perfect example of what SQL was made for.

Comment: The code must be in c for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. The problem was using resID as a common identifier instead of carID.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You're not counting the number of cars and reservations correctly:
In both loops (the one that reads cars, and the one that reads reservations), you're using `reccount` as the counter.
You need to use two counters, `carcount` and `rescount`.
Later on, then, you need to use carcount and rescount in your for loops.

```
for (k=0;k<=rescount; k++){
    if (strcmp(choice,reservation[k].reservationEndDate)<0 && strcmp(choice,reservation[k].reservationStartDate)>0){
        for (i=0;i<=carcount; i++){
```

You should also consider dynamically allocating memory for the car and reservation arrays, as well as for the character arrays inside car_t and reservation_t, since your current code will (even when the obvious bug is fixed) segfault or give unexpected results as soon as your input files have over MAX_CAR/MAX_RES lines, or the strings in the lines are too long.

**Update**
There are still several issues with your updated code:

- You should not store data that's not supposed to be a string in a string variable. Store as much as possible in integer or unsigned variables, especially IDs and dates.
- Speaking about dates: Simply use `time(NULL)` to get the current time in UNIX time format ("seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00"). Store all dates as an integer in UNIX time.
- When reading the file, check if carcount is greater than CAR_MAX

  ```
  for(carcount = 0; carcount < CAR_MAX; carcount++)
  ```
- You should use fscanf when reading the textfile:

  ```
  if(fscanf(filehandle, "R%03u...\n", &car[carcount].reservationID, ...) == EOF)
      break;
  ```

  This will make your file scanning much more robust and turn it into a one-liner.
- Avoid string comparisions wherever possible. Instead, use 'real datatypes'.
- Avoid gotos, really. It is true that Linux kernel developers use them, but they know what they're doing.
- Your outer for loop contains a break statement that will, in every case, break the loop execution after the first run. You probably forgot braces after 'else'.
- I think your program flow logic contains some errors. You `printf("\n\nno matching resID in cars.txt\n")` after every single car.

In general, have you tried debugging your code? gdb is a really powerful utility. You can use it to follow the program flow, pause your program at look at variable contents at any time.